# Configuring a custom domain giving error

Tags: custom-domain, mydomain

I have followed all the steps mentioned at http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653

Domain configured: abc-def.ghi.jk.lm
("abc-def" is a sub domain to "ghi.jk.lm domain")

CName in my DNS Management:
abc-def.ghi.jk.lm.00d..........live.siteforce.com

When I am pointing a domain to my hosting IP, then the domain is working
fine, but when I point it to Salesforce through a CNAME it is going to
server not found.

I have contacted hosting provider and they said all is working fine at
their end, which seems to be a fair statement as it is not working only
when I am having a CNAME.

Please assist

Comment: Is your certificate for http or https? That could be the source of your issue. I believe if you search the forum you'll discover that this question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: no issue with the certificate , Although in http://mxtoolbox.com/ it shows cname not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with the sandbox , As Cname can't be used in sandbox